# MariaDB select record for every find_in_set values

Tags: mariadb, find-in-set

I'm pretty sure there are already topics on this subject. I just can't find them. Sorry...

I want to select rows from a table where column = 1 or 2, or 3, or 3.

I need to use FIND_IN_SET because I don't know those numbers.

What I have now is (the numbers are an example):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(my_column, '1,2,3,3')
```

The query, sure, returns 3 rows.

I need 4, cause I have 4 numbers...

Comment: 'I need to use FIND_IN_SET' - I doubt it AND I don't really understand what you are asking. Are you saying if a number appears twice in the set that you should get 2 rows, if a number appears in the set three times you should get 3 rows (etc)?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Oh.... I'm using MariaDB 10.3.12... I will edit the keywords right away...

Comment: How are you generating the query? Is the string `'1,2,3,3'` a value from another table? or is it coming from your application?

Comment: Is coming from my app (with php).

Comment: Are there always 4 numbers? If not, what is the maximum?

Comment: I don't know the maximum...

Comment: you would have to go deliverd table a.k.a subquery ... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ) AS selections INNER JOIN your_table ON selections.id = your_table.my_column ORDER BY selections.id ASC` ..

Comment: See also `my_col IN (1,2,3,3)`